# Definition 4.1 Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Walter Rudin.When $p$ is an isolated point of $E$, $\lim_{x \to p} f(x) = q$ is not defined.

Tags: calculus, limits, metric-spaces

I am reading "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Walter Rudin.

> Definition 4.1
>
> Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces; suppose $E \subset X$, $f$ maps $E$ into $Y$, and $p$ is a limit point of $E$. We write $f(x) \to q$ as $x \to p$, or $$\lim_{x \to p} f(x) = q$$
> if there is a point $q \in Y$ with the following property: For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $$d_Y(f(x), q) < \epsilon$$
> for all points $x \in E$ for which $$0 < d_X(x, p) < \delta.$$

When $p$ is an isolated point of $E$, $$\lim_{x \to p} f(x) = q$$ is not defined.

Let $p$ be an isolated point of $E$.

There exists a $\delta_0 > 0$ such that there are no points $x \in E$ for which $$0 < d_X(x, p) < \delta_0.$$

So, for every $\epsilon > 0$ and for every $q \in Y$ $$d_Y(f(x), q) < \epsilon$$
for all points $x \in E$ for which $$0 < d_X(x, p) < \delta_0.$$

Rudin didn't want multiple limits at $p$?

$p$ is a point in $E$, so I think it is not natural to exclude limit at $p$.

Comment: Yes, Rudin didn't want multiple limits as $x$ approaches $p$.

Comment: Thank you very much, etemalGoldenBraid.

Comment: In other words, every function is continuous at every isolated point.

Comment: Thank you very much, William Elliot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess not, since the definition appears to work "vacuously" for every $q\in Y$.

It seems natural to say the definition doesn't work for an isolated point.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Chris Custer.